How to use environment variables in vite.config.js file for proxy in Vite
I am trying to access the environment variables in vite.config.js file, but there is an error while using import.meta.env.ENV_VARIABLE_NAME.
I have a vite.config.js file in which I am using proxy. The code for the same is given below.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    proxy:{
      '/api':{
        target: 'http://localhost:3000'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})

Now I want to add the target backend url as an environment variable. I have created a .env file and added an environment variable with name VITE_BACKEND_API_URL='http://localhost:3000'. But I am not able to access it in vite.config file by import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_API_URL.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    proxy:{
      '/api':{
        target: import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_API_URL
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})

This is the error on terminal
failed to load config from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Frontend\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_BACKEND_API_URL')

Please help me for this.

what makes you think .env is being read by anything?

this answer is the way to do it - changed link to better answer :p

import { loadEnv } from 'vite';

const env = loadEnv(process.env.NODE_ENV as string, process.cwd(), 'VITE_');

export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    proxy:{
      '/api':{
        target: env.VITE_BACKEND_API_URL
      }
    }
  }
})


Please explain what you've changed to address the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers
